# C#: Services access the dataprovider class running the sql statements - correct approach?

Tags: c#, sql, service, data-access-layer, dataprovider

is this a common and/or good approach?

In my ViewModel(Wpf) or Presenter(WinForms) I do this:

```
ICustomerService customerService = MyService.GetService<ICustomerService>();
ICustomerList customerList = customerService.GetCustomers();
```

the CustomerService class looks like this:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
     public ICustomerList GetCustomers()
     {
        return _customerDataProvider.GetCustomers();
     }
}

public class CustomerDataProvider()
{
    public ICustomerList GetCustomers()
    {
       // Open SQL connection,
       // get back a SqlDataReader and iterate it
       // in the loop write all data into a ICustomer object
       // add the ICustomer object to the ICustomerList
       // return ICustomerList object... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving data from a database is the plumbing of your application.  And the less plumbing you have to write yourself, the more productive you will be.

I usually go to LINQ directly in the client:

```
 sp_GetCustomersResult customers;
 using (var db = new DbDataContext(ConnectionString))
      customers = db.sp_GetCustomers();
```

This works fairly well, and lets me focus on adding customer value instead of database access layers.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found much value in declaring interfaces for business classes or for custom collections since extension methods became available. I would have `GetCustomers` return `IEnumerable<Customer>`.

If you plan on working extensively with business objects then you should look into using an object/relation mapper such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx). Or use LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework to reduce the amount of repetitive plumbing code you have to write.

Comment: Well not extensively...about 10 different entities not more. Most of them are aggregated somehow into the other entity.

If I would go for a ORM I would choose EF 4 because I used learned it for 8 months but I wasnt satisfied by the sql ce support bundled with EF 4 for example I do not have identity columns instead I have to fight around with Guid`s in the code ... terrible... or the designer support is very bad. Stuff like this makes me wanting using the pure sql where many good IDE`s exist and I have the full sql power, no restrictions by ORM tool.

At the moment I think about using sqlite.

Comment: What has Extension methods to do with IEnumerable<Customer> ?